# Change the maven surefire reportsDirectory using command line

Tags: maven, testing, maven-surefire-plugin

I'm looking to save generated reports into a custom location for each of my test suites(for example, ../target/api/surefire-reports, ../target/ui/surefire-reports)

I can do this by adding the below line in the pom.xml

```
<configuration>
  <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/api/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>

   <suiteXmlFiles>
     <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/api_testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>                        
   </suiteXmlFiles>
</configuration>
```

However, I want to use command line, and was trying this:

```
mvn clean test -Dsurefire.suiteXmlFiles=src\\test\\resources\\api_testng.xml -DreportsDirectory=${project.build.directory}\\apitests\\surefire-reports
```

but, it doesn't work and saves the reports in the usual ../target/surefire-reports folder, and doesn't throw any errors as well.

This is quite possible in maven surefire report plugin, like this

```
mvn surefire-report:report -DoutputDirectory=newpath
```

Does anyone know or have used the command line option to do this in surefire?

Comment: Why do you need to save generated reports? are you using a CI solution like Jenkins? Apart from that it would be helpful to have a full pom file ...Furthermore if you try to configure on command you should use an absolute path...BTW: Are you trying to run this from within IDE or plain command line?

Comment: Yes, they are part of a Jenkins pipeline, which runs the maven command. 
The reason why I need to save it separately is, as after the stage which runs the API tests finishes, it generates the reports in target/surefire-reports, however, when the stage which runs UI tests starts it overrides the target/surefire-reports folder and saves its reports there, hence, as the API test results are lost, I want to save the report in theri respective folders.

Answer (score 0):

The `-D` switch allows you to override *properties* from the CLI. So define a property and use that as the value of `<reportsDirectory>`, like so:

```xml
<properties>
    <surefireReportsDirectory/><!-- Empty means use the default value. -->
</properties>
...
<plugins>
...
<plugin>
    ...
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <reportsDirectory>${surefireReportsDirectory}</reportsDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
</plugins>
```

Now you can change it from the CLI:

```
mvn -DsurefireReportsDirectory=/some/other/dir test
```